# Migrating social_auth to django_social using Django 1.11 and Python 3.6

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I'm having problem while trying to migrate social_auth module to django_social using Django 1.11 and Python 3.6. I have some models in my models.py file that uses

```
from social_auth.signals import pre_update, socialauth_registered
from social_auth.backends.facebook import FacebookBackend
from social_auth.backends.twitter import TwitterBackend
```

but I can't find the equivalent to `social_auth.signals` into `django_social`

Are they deprecated? Is there a newer version to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`signals.py`](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/8bbaff07f24d27f3e522d9b0c93ee3f3d9918b6b/social_auth/signals.py) file from a past revision, it looks like signals were deprecated and are no longer used.

> ```
> # This module is deprecated, this signals aren't used by the code anymore
> # and it's functionality should be replaced by pipeline methods.
> ```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check for the new pipeline methods then